# Selenium finding ip address of chrome

Tags: python, selenium, vb6

I'm using a vpn and it only changes ip address of chrome. Sometimes my vpn connection goes down and I want to know when it happens and I want to be able to know that by comparing my local ip address and chromes ip address so that if they are equal I will know that my vpn connection is down.

Is there any possibility to see my chrome's ip address that selenium makes (using seleniums any function or without using doesn't matter)? I need to get that ip not just for only this case, that's why I don't use try catch.

Is there any way to find my chrome's ip address that selenium makes with VB 6.0 and with Python?

Comment: Open http://ipinfo.io/ip ?

Comment: If you're using (or not) `Try  Catch`, then you're not using vb6, but vb.net?  So the tags are incorrect on the question? Perhaps, for vb.net, you can investigate the network information classes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: just to be clear, your browser does not have an IP address (an IP connected device has an IP), your traffic is being sent from a certain IP to an endpoint.  Technically your IP never changes, so what you really need is a hook at the level of whatever application is directing your traffic to the VPN.  (So check for an API that tells you if it is "falling back" to direct connection when the VPN goes down.)

Comment: Can you please distinguish what is being done in VB, and what is in Python? As the question is written, this is not very clear.

Comment: Same thing will happen in VB and in Python. It's not necessary to use both of them. My question is, when i use vpn https://ipinfo.io/ip website gives my ip which i use with vpn. Can i do the same thing using either with vb or python? Or with selenium?